# How to develop: Web server and mobile clients

Tags: php, android, mobile, webserver, client-server

I want to link (in both directions) mobile clients (Android, etc.) with the Web application (central server). In other words : mobile Client-Server communication.

I'm new to developing for Android, but had on the development of PHP and MySQL.

Specify, please, the right direction for me: what technologies to use (REST, JSON, XML or something else), OAuth Authorization, there can be [micro] framework for PHP for these purposes.

Keywords, links to best articles, books, examples are welcome.

*UPD*. Yes, a lot of information in Google, I see. But I want to start **right**, use the **best practices**, of course.

Comment: You'd really get a lot of information about this here at SO and also a google search would do. BTW, do you want a bi-directional communication? You could look into XMPP then.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new in Android development and also searched a lot for doing this.I will explain how i achieved this.

For communicating with php server you need to create php [rest apis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)  [I am using flight php frame work for this ref : http://flightphp.com/ ]

In Android side you need to call this apis. For this I am using third party library retrofit (because it is easy to use) ref : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You can also use HttpURLConnection (ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) android library i think it is a bit difficulty because we need to create a asynctask and all

you can find some tutorial about how to use retrofit in google :https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+retrofit+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Android development!

First of all, design your API. You may find details [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices/). Once you have it, you can build your REST server in PHP. I am using slim framework (http://www.slimframework.com/) for routes and RedBeanPHP (http://redbeanphp.com) for database access. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-slim-rest/) is a tutorial for creating REST server with slim.

After your server is settled (or several servers), you can set up your android application.
I am actively using retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/ please refer to the v2.beta).

This is an example of how you implement it. There is magic as retrofit will convert JSON objects received from the REST server into java objects.

```
public interface RestInterface {

    @POST("/register")
    Call<RestResponse> register(@Body RestRegister register);

    @POST("/request_validation")
    Call<RestResponse> request_validation(@Header(Constants.HEADER_KEY) String header);
...
}
```

Of course, you have to implements the objects. I can give a more detailed example if you want.
You also have to create a restClient:

```
public class RestClient {
    private OkHttpClient client;
    private RestInterface restInterface;
    public RestClient()
    {
        client = new OkHttpClient(); 
        client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(Constants.WEBSERVICE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);
}
```

Finally, I have a service where I call the RestClient to get my calls. Here is a method.

```
private void handleSendingRegistration(RestRegister register) {
    final String method = "handleSendingRegistration: ";
    Call<RestResponse> response = restClient.getGatherInterface().register(register);
    response.enqueue(new RestCallback<RestResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Response<RestResponse> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, method + response.body().getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, method + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

This message is a bit crude, but you can see the idea of your question. Hope it can help you building your application.